# How do I achieve consistency in output in eps and pdf terminals in gnuplot?

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to get somewhat consistent output between eps and pdf terminals in gnuplot.  The trouble is that they seem to understand size units differently; the same specified size in inches will result in a much larger font size for the pdf output:

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced colour size 10in,8in font 'Arial-Bold,14'
set output 'my_eps.eps'
set title 'My plot'
plot sin(x) notitle

set terminal pdfcairo size 10in,8in font 'Arial-Bold,14'
set output 'my_pdf.pdf'
replot
```

The text in the .pdf is much larger and the graph is cramped.  However, if I change the size units of the eps to cm:

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced colour size 10cm,8cm font 'Arial-Bold,14'
                                                 ########
set output 'my_eps.eps'
set title 'My plot'
plot sin(x) notitle

set terminal pdfcairo size 10in,8in font 'Arial-Bold,14'
set output 'my_pdf.pdf'
replot
```

The outputs look the same (to within some margin errors) with the wrong units.  Is this a coincidence?  What's going on here?

This was tested for Gnuplot 4.4 (patchlevel 3) Ubuntu 11.10.

(I know I could use some utility to convert between eps and pdf so they would be the same, but I'd like to understand what's going on in gnuplot.)

Answer (score 3):

With the two plots in the same unit system, this behavior is expected -- although maybe not well/accurately documented.  (from `help post`)

```
In `eps` mode the whole plot, including the fonts, is reduced to half of 
the default size.
```

Since you specified a size explicitly, that part sticks, but the fonts are still reduced in size by a factor of 2 on the `eps` plot even if you specify a font explicitly (I don't know why this is, but it's always been that way -- I've always considered it a bug in the documentation at least ... ).

As far as switching the units to centimeters -- I'm not at my computer with the `cairo` terminals enabled, so I can't check right now ... but that seems odd (to me).  Is it perhaps because the conversion to centimeters from inches is about a factor of 2 which makes them look so similar?  (e.g. your fonts are half the size while your plot is 1/2.54 the size)

To achieve terminal independence, I suppose you could write it up in a function (**CURRENTLY UNTESTED**):

```
fontsize(x)=((GPVAL_TERM eq 'postscript') && \
             (strstrt(GPVAL_TERMOPTIONS,"eps")!=0)) ? x*2 : x
set term post eps enh size 10in,8in
set termoption font "Arial,".fontsize(7)
set output "Hello.eps"
plot sin(x)

set term pdfcairo enh size 10in,8in
set termoption font "Arial,".fontsize(7)
set output "Hello.pdf"
plot sin(x)
```

Make sure you only pass integers to fontsize -- integers get promoted to strings when doing string concatenation.

**EDIT**

After digging a little further, it appears that the cairo library is taking some liberties and embedding a (similar) font that you didn't ask for.

running `pdffonts myfile.pdf` -- Note that you get the fontname just by `strings myfile.pdf | grep FontName` :

```
name                 type         emb sub uni object ID
-------------------- ------------ --- --- --- ------ --
LiberationSansBold   CID TrueType yes no  yes      5 0
```

whereas the postscript just contains the font name (not embedded) which gets translated by the ps viewer as the closest thing it can find to the requested font (It [probably] substitutes a font you didn't ask for also).  So, to achieve true terminal independence (between these two terminals), you'd need to find the fontfile that was embedded in the pdf and then `set postscript eps enh color fontfile add "<fontfile>"` to embed the same fontfile in both the pdf and the postscript.

Comment: Interesting--I certainly hadn't come across that fact about the eps terminal.  I thought of the factor-of-2 issue as well--it makes more sense for things to be off by a factor of 2 than by a factor of 2.5.  However, if I just double the font size the plots do not look the same.  If I do as I have in the second code example in my post and I display the .eps and .pdf output at the same size on my screen, they overlay very closely.  The .eps is 2.5x smaller if I display the two files at 100% size in my viewer (evince), but the proportions are comparable between the two.

Comment: @andyras : It looks like your postscript viewer is substituting a different font than the cairo library is substituting.  to fix that, you'd need to figure out what font file the cairo library is embedding and embed the same one in your postscript.  See my edit.

Comment: pdffonts says the .pdf has the 'NISIPN+Arial-BoldMT' font, and searching through the .eps I find the same (Arial-Bold) font referenced throughout.  The `add fontfile` command you suggested created the same .eps as before, albeit with an embedded font file.  My .pdf and .eps can be downloaded from https://www.dropbox.com/s/rz6hx3y4m64o6sr/gnuplot_pdf_eps.tar.gz.

Answer (score 0):

### Achieve 100% consistency with Ghostscript

I use [Ghostscript](http://ghostscript.com/) to convert the Encapsulated PostScript (EPS) graph created by `gnuplot` to PDF. Works great!

```
gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=output.pdf input.eps
```

Comment: While this is true, it is not what the OP asked for, see the last sentence in the question ;)